# Values in fields can not be recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery

why can not my function register a text that is clicked, but must I enter it manually to calculate in total?
Namely, my idea is that by clicking on a product, it is displayed in the input field [284] of the product price, and when clicking on a checkbox option to increase the price and display it at the end of [388], the text menu can now only it is compiled if I enter a number manually in field 285. How can I do it?

```js
function displayAbo(el) {
 document.getElementById("contactFormFieldId_284").value = el.querySelector('.product__title').textContent+ " " +el.querySelector('.product__price').textContent;
}
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('contactFormClass_checkbox');
var sum = 0,
  inputField = document.getElementById('contactFormFieldId_284'),
  finalInput = document.getElementById('contactFormFieldId_388');

Array.prototype.slice.call(checkBoxes).forEach( (checkBox) => {
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal, false);
})

inputField.addEventListener('blur', calculateSumWithInput, false);

function calculateTotal(e) {
  if(e.target.checked) {
      sum += parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  } else {
      sum -= parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  }
   finalInput.value ="CHF "+ sum + ".–";
}

function calculateSumWithInput(e) {
  var re = /\d+/; 
  var value = re.exec(e.target.value);
  if(value && !isNaN(value) && Number(value) === parseInt(value, 10)) {
      sum = parseInt(value, 10);
      finalInput.value = sum;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__item" onclick="displayAbo(this)" id="product-medium" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-describedby="medium-desc">
  <div class="product__inner" id="medium-desc">
    <h3 class="product__title">LEUWIN M</h3>
    <ul class="product__features">
      <li class="product__features-item">40 Mbit/s</li>
      <li class="product__features-item"><img src="themes/zuerich/images/I.png" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 110px;"></li>
    </ul>
    <h4 class="product__price">CHF 39.–</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contact row">
<label for="contactFormFieldId_284" style="color: #003664; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">[[284_LABEL]]</label>
<input class="contactFormClass_text" id="contactFormFieldId_284" type="text" name="contactFormField_284" value="[[284_VALUE]]" readonly />
</div>
<div class="contact row">
<label for="contactFormFieldId_385">[[385_LABEL]]</label>
<input class="contactFormClass_checkbox" id="contactFormFieldId_385" type="checkbox" name="contactFormField_385" value="5" [[SELECTED_385]] />
</div>
<div class="contact row">
<label for="contactFormFieldId_386">[[386_LABEL]]</label>
<input class="contactFormClass_checkbox" id="contactFormFieldId_386" type="checkbox" name="contactFormField_386" value="15" [[SELECTED_386]] />
</div>
<div class="contact row">
<label for="contactFormFieldId_387">[[387_LABEL]]</label>
<input class="contactFormClass_checkbox" id="contactFormFieldId_387" type="checkbox" name="contactFormField_387" value="20" [[SELECTED_387]] />
</div>
<div class="contact row">
<label for="contactFormFieldId_388" style="color: #003664; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">[[388_LABEL]]</label>
<input class="contactFormClass_text" id="contactFormFieldId_388" type="text" name="contactFormField_388" value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question

Comment: @Rohit.007 How can I calculate the value obtained from the contactFormFieldId_284 field with the checkbox fields and display in the contactFormFieldId_388 field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made 2 changes.

1. Changed your `blur` function to `click`

   inputField.addEventListener('click', calculateSumWithInput, false);
2. Added `click` triggers in your functions

   inputField.click();

```js
function displayAbo(el) {
  document.getElementById("contactFormFieldId_284").value = el.querySelector('.product__title').textContent + " " + el.querySelector('.product__price').textContent;
  inputField.click();
}
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('contactFormClass_checkbox');
var sum = 0,
  inputField = document.getElementById('contactFormFieldId_284'),
  finalInput = document.getElementById('contactFormFieldId_388');

Array.prototype.slice.call(checkBoxes).forEach((checkBox) => {
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal, false);
})

inputField.addEventListener('click', calculateSumWithInput, false);
inputField.click();

function calculateTotal(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    sum += parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  } else {
    sum -= parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  }
  finalInput.value = "CHF " + sum + ".–";
}

function calculateSumWithInput(e) {
  var re = /\d+/;
  var value = re.exec(e.target.value);
  if (value && !isNaN(value) && Number(value) === parseInt(value, 10)) {
    sum = parseInt(value, 10);
    finalInput.value =  "CHF " + sum + ".–";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product__item" onclick="displayAbo(this)" id="product-medium" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-describedby="medium-desc">
  <div class="product__inner" id="medium-desc">
    <h3 class="product__title">LEUWIN M</h3>
    <ul class="product__features">
      <li class="product__features-item">40 Mbit/s</li>
      <li class="product__features-item"><img src="themes/zuerich/images/I.png" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 110px;"></li>
    </ul>
    <h4 class="product__price">CHF 39.–</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contact row">
  <label for="contactFormFieldId_284" style="color: #003664; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">[[284_LABEL]]</label>
  <input class="contactFormClass_text" id="contactFormFieldId_284" type="text" name="contactFormField_284" value="[[284_VALUE]]" readonly />
</div>
<div class="contact row">
  <label for="contactFormFieldId_385">[[385_LABEL]]</label>
  <input class="contactFormClass_checkbox" id="contactFormFieldId_385" type="checkbox" name="contactFormField_385" value="5" [[SELECTED_385]] />
</div>
<div class="contact row">
  <label for="contactFormFieldId_386">[[386_LABEL]]</label>
  <input class="contactFormClass_checkbox" id="contactFormFieldId_386" type="checkbox" name="contactFormField_386" value="15" [[SELECTED_386]] />
</div>
<div class="contact row">
  <label for="contactFormFieldId_387">[[387_LABEL]]</label>
  <input class="contactFormClass_checkbox" id="contactFormFieldId_387" type="checkbox" name="contactFormField_387" value="20" [[SELECTED_387]] />
</div>
<div class="contact row">
  <label for="contactFormFieldId_388" style="color: #003664; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">[[388_LABEL]]</label>
  <input class="contactFormClass_text" id="contactFormFieldId_388" type="text" name="contactFormField_388" value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: 007 This is great, thanks for the answer, I just do not know why in the [field 388] it shows CHF 284?

Comment: Should it be `0` initially?

Comment: the [[contactFormFieldId_388]] field should be displayed at CHF 39.- to click, rather than 284 as a field id

Comment: Is it my goal that when I click on a thumbnail to display total tot CHF 39.- and when the checkboxes of the field will be clicked to update the additional value

Comment: Updated the code, check if I understood it correctly.

Comment: 007 that's it, perfectly, thank you very much! You've saved my day :). Is it only possible to immediately show CHF 39.– instead of just 39